# Resend touch event to another view in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I've got an `UIImageView` on top of (and not an element of) a `UIScrollView`. Well, I've subclassed the `UIImageView` to check for touch events and have overridden the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method. Inside that method I basically send the subclassed `UIImageView` behind the `UIScrollView` element. (I use `[self.super bringSubviewToFront: scrollView]` to achieve this).

What I want is to be able to send the current touch event of the `UIImageView` to the `UIScrollView` element, so that the user doesn't have to lift his finger and touch again to scroll. I already tried to call `touchesBegan:withEvent:` on the `UIScrollView` element, but it did nothing.

Does anyone have an idea of what should be done so I could simulate the touch of the `UIImageView` to the `UIScrollView` element?

Here is the overridden method in the subclassed `UIImageView`:

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];

     ViewController* controller = [Singleton getSingleton].controller;
     [super bringSubviewToFront: controller.scrollView]; //Now scroll view is in the front

     [controller.scrollView touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event]; //Does nothing
}
```

Comment: I'm just throwing this out there, but since your touch event has already begun so I don't think a new event makes sense, when you bring the scrollview to the top, does touchesMoved get fired?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You can just make the UIImageView non-touch sensitive by setting `userInteractionEnabled = NO` (which `UIImageView` actually has as default).

Comment: @propstm The scroll view won't scroll after it is brought to the top. I didn't override the touchesMoved method. I don't override the UIScrollView, but it doesn't scroll.

Comment: @fzwo What I want to achieve is a UIImageView on top of a UIScrollView. When the UIImageView is touched, the UIScrollView is brought to front and scrolls using the same finger touch, which currently doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to override `hitTest:withEvent:` in the `UIImageView` subclass.

```
(UIView*) hitTest: (CGPoint)point withEvent: (UIEvent*)event
{
    if([self pointInside:point withEvent:event]){
         ViewController* controller = [Singleton getSingleton].controller;
         [controller.view bringSubviewToFront: controller.scrollView];
         return controller.scrollView;
    }else{
         return [super hitTest:point withEvent: event];
    }
}
```

This way, when a touch on the `UIImageView` is issued, it would first call this method, which would bring the `UIScrollView` to front and then return the `UIScrollView` as the object which should handle the event.